# Getting the whole name of an attribute knowing the beginning?

Tags: ruby

I have an object "Somebody" with many attibutes: `id, name, age, service_private...`

These attributes can be equal to `nil`.

I would like to get the name `service_private` with `service`. (I know that there is just one `service_*` in the list!)

I tried some command lines, for example:

```
someone = Somebody.new()
someone.starts_with("service") or someone[/^service/] or someone.start_with?("service")
```

but error !

Thank you.

Comment: Why did you rename my title ?  it's an attribute/variable, not a method. No ?

Comment: What you are looking for is not called a "variable" which is something completely different. I changed the title to "attributes", but know that the attributes you are looking for are actually methods in ruby.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't know. (this question was just to understand :) ) thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
someone.methods.find { |m| m[/^service/] }
# => :service_private
```

If the method is private (as the name suggests), you will need to use `private_methods` instead of methods:

```
someone.private_methods.find { |m| m[/^service/] }
# => :service_private
```

If you want to get the *value* of this attribute, you will need to call it (using `send`)

```
someone.send(someone.methods.find { |m| m[/^service/] })
# => 'some value'
```

Comment: Oops!! Sorry I thought you forgot to write, so I edited it.. :)

Comment: Thank you ! It works very well ! 
Edit : I had understood and I have well used "private_methods" :)

Answer (score 4):

[`Enumerable#grep`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) can be helpful here.

> Returns an array of every element in enum for which `Pattern === element`. If the optional block is supplied, each matching element is passed to it, and the block’s result is stored in the output array.

```
someone.methods.grep /^service/
```

If you want to list [*private methods*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-private_methods)

```
someone.private_methods.grep /^service/
```

Because [`#methods`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-methods) gives you only *a list of the names of public and protected methods of obj..*